# Screen appearing reversed during screen sharing and when using the Media Projection API

Tags: java, android, kotlin, chromebook

Chromebook Version: Version 118.0.5993.86 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Issue: When performing screen sharing on a Chromebook, the shared screen appears reversed.

Issue: When using the Media Projection API to capture screenshots on a Chromebook, the captured images also appear reversed.

Is the problem of the screen appearing reversed during screen sharing and when using the Media Projection API to capture screenshots still present in the latest Chromebook version release?

[image]

Comment: How does this pertain to java, kotlin, or android?